# Подскажите в чем проблема. Ошибка ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND при появлении картинки в окне

Tags: javascript, html, css

При нажатии на галерею изображений, должно всплывать фото в отдельном окне , но почему то при нажатии происходит ошибка ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="container-gallery">
        <div class="gallery">
            <div class="gallary-item">
                <div class="gallary-icon">
                    <img src="./imagesAuto/rapid3.jpg" width="220" height="162">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallary-item">
                <div class="gallary-icon">
                    <img src="./imagesAuto/rapid4.jpg" width="220" height="162">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallary-item">
                <div class="gallary-icon">
                    <img src="./imagesAuto/rapid5.jpg" width="220" height="162">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallary-item">
                <div class="gallary-icon">
                    <img src="./imagesAuto/rapid6.jpg" width="220" height="162">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallary-item">
                <div class="gallary-icon">
                    <img src="./imagesAuto/rapid2.jpg" width="220" height="162">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallary-item">
                <div class="gallary-icon">
                    <img src="./imagesAuto/rapid7.jpg" width="220" height="162">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallary-item">
                <div class="gallary-icon">
                    <img src="./imagesAuto/rapid8.jpg" width="220" height="162">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallary-item">
                <div class="gallary-icon">
                    <img src="./imagesAuto/rapid9.jpg" width="220" height="162">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallary-item">
                <div class="gallary-icon">
                    <img src="./imagesAuto/rapid10.jpg" width="220" height="162">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pop-up">
            <span>&times;</span>
            <img src="./imagesAuto/rapid8.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: auto
}

.gallery .gallary-item {
    width: 32% !important;
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0 0 14px !important;
}
.container-gallery .pop-up{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    display: none;
}
.container-gallery .pop-up img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50% );
}
.container-gallery .pop-up span{
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.gallery .gallary-item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: none !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

js

```
document.querySelectorAll('.container-gallery .gallary-icon').forEach(img =>{
  img.onclick = () => {
    document.querySelector('.pop-up'). style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".pop-up img"). src = img.getAttribute('src');
  }
});

document.querySelector('.pop-up span').onclick = () => {
  document.querySelector('.pop-up'). style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в контексте

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.container-gallery .gallary-icon').forEach(img => {
  
  img.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
    const {src} = target
     document.querySelector('.pop-up').style.display = "block";
     document.querySelector(".pop-up img").src = src;
  })
});

document.querySelector('.pop-up span').onclick = () => {
  document.querySelector('.pop-up').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto
}

.gallery .gallary-item {
  width: 32% !important;
  float: none !important;
  margin: 0 0 14px !important;
}

.container-gallery .pop-up {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.container-gallery .pop-up img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container-gallery .pop-up span {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery .gallary-item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-gallery">
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallary-item">
      <div class="gallary-icon">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQqCjHYJyPsVir6S7VjWMbwuz7sH4aaRRiyYMlG0JkU&s" width="220" height="162">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallary-item">
      <div class="gallary-icon">
        <img src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-under-mist-morning-amazing-260nw-1725825019.jpg" width="220" height="162">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pop-up">
    <span>&times;</span>
    <img src="./imagesAuto/rapid8.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое